# Styling .toolbar-container of ion-toolbar shadow dom in ionic 4+

Tags: css, ionic-framework, dom, sass, ionic4

I've tried lots of methods. but not working.
Expect like this style

```
ion-toolbar {
    contain: none;
    .toolbar-container {
        overflow: visible;  // not working
        contain: none;  // not working
    }
}
```

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked around this issue with a new Directive:

`ng generate directive allow-overflow`

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAllowOverflow]'
})
export class AllowOverflowDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef)
  {
    let toolbar : HTMLElement = el.nativeElement;
    setTimeout(() => {
      let container : HTMLElement = toolbar.shadowRoot.querySelector(".toolbar-container");
      if (container)
      {
        // (as any) is just to suppress a warning
        (container.style as any).contain = "none";
        container.style.overflow = "visible";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then I added the `<ion-toolbar>` like this:

```
<ion-toolbar appAllowOverflow>
    ...
</ion-toolbar>
```

I also added this CSS rule for `<ion-toolbar>`:

```
ion-toolbar[appAllowOverflow]
{
  contain: none;
}
```